# How to install SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle properly?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am really getting nervous because of lacking of enough resource for installing SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle and it's dependencies like sonataUserBundle. I have been trying to install this bundle for 15 days. I did everyting agaian and again what telling in sonata's official page. But it does not work properly. After extending sonataUserBundle as ApplicationUserBundle my final documents are:

**User.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of the <name> project.
 *
 * (c) <yourname> <youremail>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the EasyExtends bundle ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends )
 *
 * References :
 *   working with object : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html
 *
 * @author <yourname> <youremail>
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Group.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of the <name> project.
 *
 * (c) <yourname> <youremail>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseGroup as BaseGroup;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the EasyExtends bundle ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends )
 *
 * References :
 *   working with object : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html
 *
 * @author <yourname> <youremail>
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true


# app/config/config.yml
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:      


sonata_user:
    security_acl: false
    manager_type: mongodb # can be orm or mongodb

sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role

    title:      Sonatas Project
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig

    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

            # Customize this part to add new block configuration
            - { position: right, type: sonata.block.service.text, settings: { content: "<h2>Welcome to the Sonata Admin</h2> <p>This is a <code>sonata.block.service.text</code> from the Block Bundle, you can create and add new block in these area by configuring the <code>sonata_admin</code> section.</p> <br /> For instance, here a RSS feed parser (<code>sonata.block.service.rss</code>):"} }
            - { position: right, type: sonata.block.service.rss, settings: { title: Sonata Project's Feeds, url: http://sonata-project.org/blog/archive.rss }}

    # set to true to persist filter settings per admin module in the user's session

fos_user:
    db_driver:      mongodb # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\User

    group:
        group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\Group
```

**security.yml**

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            switch_user:        true
            context:            user
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                use_referer:    true
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
                target:         /admin/login

            anonymous:    true
        # -> end custom configuration

        # defaut login area for standard users
        main:
            switch_user:        true
            context:            user
            pattern:            .*
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # -> custom access control for the admin area of the URL
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # -> end

        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

After all I run:

```
php app/console fos:user:create --super-admin
```

The task tells me the user created succesfully. Then I check my mongodb and there is only a record with 3 fields.

Here is the output:

```
> db.fos_user_user.findOne();
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-05-25T19:43:52Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-05-25T19:43:52Z"),
    "gender" : "u"
}
```

As you see there is no a username or password or another field which pointed in sonata's or fos' document files.  I installed SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle to look if there is any problem with SonataAdminBundle but it works like a charm with mysql.

I am getting so crazy. Please tell me, what is the correct way to install sonataAdminBundle with mongoDB?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Your configuration looks fine, did you try adding ```public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }``` in your user class?

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau yes __construct() method has already added but nothing has changed.

Comment: @user1150508 did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that inheritance mapping is not working right, I followed the instructions but it lead to same problem. I got it fixed by changing reference to BaseUser to class provided by FOS\UserBundle

```
# Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\User.php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document;

//use Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
```

Comment: Yes, as you say, I used FOS\UserBundle\Document\User, bu after this, some errors has been occured when using sonata admin such as 'there is no username field'. There is a bug about inheritance mapping. I have made tons of search, and tried to refactor the code, finally could not find the magic solution. And I havily need a magic solution.

Comment: I ran into other problems with Mongo and SonataMediaBundle & decided to use MySQL. Mongo & Sonata seem to a bit incomplete still..

Answer (score 1):

I was also having issues with this, the users were created with just an ID, gender: 'u', createdAt, etc. And with this, I was able to make it work:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test
    document_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                SonataUserBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
```

I hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stucked at the same point.

I created user.php in a different folder with a different name, for my organization.

The difference was that I put direcly mongodb annotations

```
namespace myProject\BackEndBundle\Document;

use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class BackEndUser extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Now user creation and authentication works, but user management in SonataAdminBundle don't works.