# PageableManagerInterface error in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.4, sonata-user-bundle

I'm trying to configure SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle to use mongodb and am getting the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load interface "PageableManagerInterface" from namespace "Sonata\CoreBundle\Model" in /Users/me/Sites/mynamespace-webtools/vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Model/UserManagerInterface.php line 25. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this? I was also getting the symptoms described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753475/how-to-install-sonatadoctrinemongodbadminbundle-properly) and have tried the answers suggested there.

Can anyone confirm if the mongodb functionality is just broken? Am also wondering if this error relates to this [commit](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/commit/a66441804b67c92b01172a22f01a3a0a437b781b)?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a dependency error within the Sonata system itself, and not strictly related to the MongoDB module.

The PageableManagerInterface class is provided by the Sonata Core Bundle. Make sure that you have it in your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
}
```

After that, make sure your install is up to date and clean your cache, as usual:

```
php composer.phar self-update ; php composer.phar update
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! This commit did it: [https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/commit/a66441804b67c92b01172a22f01a3a0a437b781b]

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to accept my answer as well if you feel it addressed the issue :)